# Is it Haram to ask God question speak to him while not looking for a direct response

Tags: salat, allah

Sometimes when something is troubling me or im loney and its not time for Salat I ask allah S.W.T questions and tell him my woes never expecting a direct answer is this Haram?

Comment: I assume that it would be helpful if you added some more information: Example of questions you ask... Use the **edit** link at the bottom of your post for that.

Answer (score 3):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته - This actually a common theme of question among new Muslims, or those who have recently returned to Islam. Generally asked by those who in their previous religions were taught that they should have a very friendly approach to God, sort of like a personal friend kind of approach, and for those who return to Islam, they speak to God in a direct way not knowing the correct etiquette when addressing their concerns to the Lord of the Universe. To address this issue:

❶ - In Islam, there is the concept of Dua (Supplication, the calling to Allah) who already knows your needs in advance. The dua is an expression of tawheed (which is the essence of Islam), where you expressly acknowledge God's power over your situation and the ability to help you and knowing that He hears you so on. As a result, the Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم called this (dua) as worship, because in reality, it is an expression of worship. Since it is worship, and since the purpose of Islam in all it's facets is to teach us how to worship God in every aspect of life, you would expect that there are many etiquettes of dua and also direct examples of dua we are asked to use, and this is what you will find in various places, throughout Qur'an and Sunnah. I recommend that to be the way you "speak to" God.

❷ - **ANSWER:** The above was needed as background info so you can understand the answer which is here. You mentioned that when you ask of God, you are "never expecting a direct answer... is this Haram". It is of one of the most essential & important requisites & etiquette of asking God that you expect a response, and it is considered unbecoming to ask God without expecting a response. Reference:

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   ‏ "‏ ادْعُوا اللَّهَ وَأَنْتُمْ مُوقِنُونَ بِالإِجَابَةِ وَاعْلَمُوا
>   أَنَّ اللَّهَ لاَ يَسْتَجِيبُ دُعَاءً مِنْ قَلْبٍ غَافِلٍ لاَهٍ ‏" -
>   Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “Call upon
>   Allah while being certain of being answered, and know that Allah does
>   not respond to a supplication from the heart of one heedless and
>   occupied by play.” (At-Tirmidhi, Hasan by al-Albani).

❸ - Once the above is done, with the other more important requisite (which is ensuring there is no shirk and kufr in your beliefs, i.e., that you are truly asking Allah and knowing Him to be your true God), then you will certainly be answered. (Either you will be given what you wish, or some sins forgiven, or some harm averted, or some reward in the Hereafter).

This is just a brief explanation. Whole scholarly works have been written on the etiquette of Dua/Supplication, as well as thousands of references in Qur'an & Sunnah which teach us the best words to use when calling on Allah.

❹ - An example (to encourage you to learn the way to call God from Qur'an and Sunnah), one of the most beautiful dua, spoken by the Prophet when he was in the most difficult time of his life (read seerah, the story of the Prophet's life to understand why it was the most difficult circumstances he faced). In that time of immense difficulty, he journeyed to Ta'if, and was violently rebuked as well as mocked, until he fled that area, and upon resting, he said the following:

> “O Allah! I complain to You of my weakness, my scarcity of resources
>   and the humiliation I have been subjected to by the people. O Most
>   Merciful of those who are merciful. O Lord of the weak and my Lord
>   too. To whom have you entrusted me? To a distant person who receives
>   me with hostility? Or to an enemy to whom you have granted authority
>   over my affair? So long as You are not angry with me, I do not care.
>   Your favor is of a more expansive relief to me. I seek refuge in the
>   light of Your Face by which all darkness is dispelled and every affair
>   of this world and the next is set right, lest Your anger or Your
>   displeasure descends upon me. I desire Your pleasure and satisfaction
>   until You are pleased. There is no power and no might except by You.”

You can find this in arabic by a quick search for the dua at Ta'if. And I will leave you to discover for yourself the effects of such a powerful, sincere dua.